# How correctly call "telnet" with CreateProcess function?

Tags: winapi, command-line, cmd, telnet, createprocess

I want to start "telnet" through cmd.exe and write the result of this command execution into file. When I run "ipconfig" command I get all information I need, but after running of "telnet" command I get just empty file.

Here is my code:

```
#include "windows.h"
#include "iostream"

void SaveResult(const wchar_t *fileName, const wchar_t *commandLine)
{
    SECURITY_ATTRIBUTES sa;
    sa.nLength = sizeof(sa);
    sa.lpSecurityDescriptor = NULL;
    sa.bInheritHandle = TRUE;

    HANDLE h = CreateFile(fileName, FILE_WRITE_DATA, FILE_SHARE_WRITE | FILE_SHARE_READ,
        &sa, OPEN_ALWAYS, FILE_ATTRIBUTE_NORMAL, NULL);
    if (h == INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE)
        return;

    PROCESS_INFORMATION pi = { 0 };
    STARTUPINFO si = { sizeof(si) };
    si.dwFlags |= STARTF_USESTDHANDLES;
    si.hStdInput = NULL;
    si.hStdError = h;
    si.hStdOutput = h;

    wchar_t *writable_cmdline = _wcsdup(commandLine);
    BOOL success = CreateProcess(NULL, writable_cmdline,
        NULL, NULL, TRUE, CREATE_NO_WINDOW, NULL, NULL, &si, &pi);

    bool finished = false;

    //wait for 1 second
    for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
    {
        if (WaitForSingleObject(pi.hProcess, 100) <= 0)
        {
            finished = true;
            break;
        }
    }

    if (success)
    {
        CloseHandle(pi.hProcess);
        CloseHandle(pi.hThread);
    }

    CloseHandle(h);
    free(writable_cmdline);

    if (!finished)
        printf("Process didn't finish\n");
}


int main()
{
    SaveResult(L"telnet.txt", L"C:\\windows\\system32\\cmd.exe /c telnet test.com");
    SaveResult(L"ipconfig.txt", L"C:\\windows\\system32\\cmd.exe /c ipconfig");
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Lots of very strange code here. Not checking the value of `success` is a bad start. Do that. And `CreateProcess` fails, call `GetLastError` to find out why. Calling `WaitForSingleObject` 10 times is pointless. call it once with a timeout 10 times longer. Better hope that the 1s is enough. What if it isn't? Calling `WaitForSingleObject` if `CreateProcess` fails is wrong. Finally, the most important skill that novice programmers lack is debugging. Take some time to learn how to debug your programs.

Comment: What do you need this for anyway? WinAPI provides [WinINet](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/wininet/about-wininet) for direct internet access

Answer (score 0):

Have you run telnet command directly in cmd console? Is there anything output? if so, The empty file may because the buffer has not been refreshed to the file. As@David pointed out,
you just wait for 1s, but if there be more than 1s to connect, then you will close the handler without refresh the buffer. Try to add the `FlushFileBuffers(h)` before `CloseHandle(h)`. 
For `WaitForSingleObject`, you could try `WaitForSingleObject(pi.hProcess, INFINITE)`, wait until the telnet process exit.